# DevExpress Get Selected Cell DataGridView

Tags: devexpress

I am having a bit of issues getting the ItemId of a selected Cell on my datagridview. The column ItemId is hidden from the user.

Any help will greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
  private void btnReturn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           Id = gridView1.GetFocusedDataRow()["ItemId"].ToString();
           MessageBox.Show(Id);
       }
```

[Sample UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJvZT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this - [Obtaining and Setting Cell Values](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument753)

> It is possible to get the values of cells using the methods provided
>   by the grid's data source. For instance, the [ColumnView.GetRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetRowtopic.aspx),
>   [ColumnView.GetDataRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetDataRowtopic.aspx), [ColumnView.GetFocusedRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetFocusedRowtopic.aspx) and
>   [ColumnView.GetFocusedDataRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetFocusedDataRowtopic.aspx) methods return objects that
>   represent rows in a data source. After rows are obtained, use their
>   methods to retrieve field values.

For example, If your grid bind to a DataTable then you can get underlying data row for selected row in grid as below:

```
System.Data.DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle);
string cellValue = row[0].ToString();
```

If it is bind to some object data source then use GetRow method and cast it to your class object. Then you can access .ItemID property of that object.

```
MyClass row = gridView1.GetRow(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle) as MyClass;
if(row != null)
  string id= row.ItemID;
```

Hope this reference help you..